# About w3c dom to update xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom, transform

I want to use **w3c.dom** to update xml and create a new file. I had use transform like this:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(newXml);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(target);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I use setTextContent to update a document file to newxml,
but the new file(result) encoding  is different with newXml.
I know that I can use

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, newXml.getXmlEncoding());
```

but I hope the result **document type** and **encoding typesetting** is **same** with original file(newXml).

Hope someone to know how to do, thank you~

Comment: The underlying output stream that is used by the Transformer is created using the same encoding, so there should be no problem.

Comment: I check the new file(result),the encoding is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>,
But original is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="big5"?>

Comment: How is `target` defined?

Comment: The target was not specifically defined.I hope that the encoding and definition of the target is the same as the original file(newxml).

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoding -decoding patterns .First convert the xml into base64 and then reconvert it into xml .